# Ajax-Generated Element Values In Form Won't Post to PHP

Tags: ajax, forms, post, drop-down-menu

Although I'm getting correct options for an ajax-generated drop-down (based on the selection of another), I'm not seeing the value post to the PHP script.  However, I see all the values from the normal HTML elements (not generated by ajax).  What am I missing?

**1. HTML produced by my scr_ajax.php script.** - OK

$options is produced by the SQL query and the resulting selections are accurate.  This is nearly identical to drop_down_1.).

```
<td>Drop Down 2</td>
<td></td>
<td>
<select name="drop_down_2" id="drop_down_2" value="" style="width:100%">
<option></option>
'.$options.'
</select>
</td>';
```

**2. Where the ajax-generated HTML data goes..** - OK

Properly receives AJAX-generated form element above for the 2nd drop-down.):

```
... 
<tr id="ajaxContent">
</tr>
...
```

**3. Regular 'ol submit button..** - Not OK

drop_down_1 can be captured in $_POST data, but drop_down_2 cannot.  I know I'm missing something here..)

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Request" />
```

Answer (score 1):

better start using jquery for everyday tasks.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, agreed but I'm looking for a more specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE: 11-25-2012]**

I'm now able to combine the HTML and AJAX-generated post results by using the jQuery submit listener and populating the hidden field.  However, this seems like more of a special technique/workaround as opposed to a more direct approach.

1st, I added the hidden input element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="drop_down_2" id="drop_down_2" value="" />
```

2nd, I added the jQuery submit listener:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form_name").submit(function() {
        var field = "drop_down_2";
        var param = document.getElementById(field).options[document.getElementById(field).selectedIndex].value;
        document.forms[0].elements[field].value = param;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**[UPDATE: 12-01-2012]**
It sounds like the proper solution involves mastery of the serialize function.  I will post an update upon verification.